# how to give a dash border to a rectangular uiview in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have all ready tried tried

```
extension UIView {
    @discardableResult
    func addLineDashedStroke(pattern: [NSNumber]?, radius: CGFloat, color: CGColor) -> CALayer {
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.strokeColor = color
        borderLayer.lineDashPattern = pattern
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        borderLayer.fillColor = nil
        borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        return borderLayer
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the use of pattern?

Comment: You wrote code that creates a shape layer that adds a dashed border. Are you unsure how to use that layer?

Comment: What's your issue exactly? what values gives to `pattern`? If that's the case, did you see the doc with its sample: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521921-linedashpattern?language=objc ?

Comment: I just want to have a dashed border in rectangular view and the above code is not applying bash to the bottom part of the view else working fine]

Comment: Did you read the documentation and the sample to understand how it works on my previous linkl? "I just want to have a dashed border" There are plenty of different settings for the dash! And did you call that method at least? How? Your issue is unclear. Else, just write `pattern: [5, 5]`, that might be the pattern you are looking for but that's a pure guess since you don't give details...

Comment: i am calling with:-

Comment: containerView.addLineDashedStroke(pattern: [1,1], radius: 10, color: UIColor.black.cgColor)

Comment: Where is this called? What's your actual result? What's `containerView.frame` when this method is called?

Answer (score 1):

That extension adds a function to `UIView` that creates and returns a dashed border CAShapeLayer. It doesn't do anything with the layer. If you just call the function and don't do anything with the layer it returns, you won't see any change.

I was able to use the extension in your question to add a dashed, rounded-corner border around a view quite easily:

Here is a custom subclass of UIViewController I implemented in a test app (I added a UIView in the storyboard and linked it to the IBOutlet `dashedBorderView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dashedBorderView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let dashedBorderLayer = dashedBorderView.addLineDashedStroke(pattern: [2, 5], radius: 10, color: UIColor.black.cgColor)
        dashedBorderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorderLayer)
    }
}
```

That code creates a bordered view that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: But before the return there is `layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)` shouldn't it work then? I'm wondering if the issue was not having the correct pattern OR premature layout (not resizing the layer on didLayout)

Comment: Oh, there is an addSublayer in there, isn't there? I missed that. I'm not sure why it isn't working, then. Edit your question to show the code that uses that function if you want help debugging it.